# Propel Syntax Error Received when using reserved keywords in table or column names

Tags: mysql, postgresql, syntax-error, propel, propel2

Is there a way to have Propel automatically escape column names which are reserved words when adding/updating a row?

Right now I have a column named 'order' and when I try to update using

```
$row->setOrder(1)->save();
```

I get a syntax error "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "order"\nLINE 1: UPDATE terms SET order=$1 WHERE terms.id=$2\n                         ^'"

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer to this at http://propelorm.org/documentation/reference/schema.html#database-element.

Adding the parameter `identifierQuoting="true"` to my `<database>` tag in my schema.xml fixed the problem.  I believe you can also add that to a `<table>` tag to limit it to a single table.  I'm not sure why this wouldn't be the default setting.

Comment: I can guess that it is the common rule for every programming language: do not use reserved words as identifiers :o)

Comment: @Abelisto it's not just "identifier". It's a column name. So if you have an "order" column in your DB logic - why you should change it to something else? Simpler is to escape the sql query fields.
Actual issue is that Propel does not escape fields/names by default.